# How to turn this ifs statement to switch statement. in C language

Tags: c, computer-science

```
int op_type(const char *input, int op_pos)
{
    int category;

    if (input[op_pos] == '+')
        category = 1;

    if (input[op_pos] == '*')
        category = 2;

    if (input[op_pos] == '/')
        category = 3;

    if (input[op_pos] == '^')
        category = 4;

    return category;
}
```

This function will be used for doing basic math.

Comment: ... and keep the broken logic of an indeterminate value of `category` returned in the event *none* of the four options match?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Have you studied the `switch` statement and understood its use?

Comment: It is unclear what about the use and syntax of `switch` is unclear to you. Please show the code from any tutorial on it you have studied and explain what is an obstacle for you. Turning the shown code into using switch is probably exactly the example used in 4 out of 5 basic C tutorials. So please understand that it is hard to understand what you need explained. The documentation alone (e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/switch ) is already generous with examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically the answer should be:

```
int op_type(const char *input, int op_pos)
{
    int category;
    switch (input[op_pos]){
        case '+':
             category = 1;
             break;
        case '*':
             category = 2;
             break;
        case '/':
             category = 3;
             break;
        case '^':
             category = 4;
             break;
    }
    return category;
}
```

Hope this answered your question.